# UDP Java Wont send message

Tags: java, network-programming, udp

Hello friends how are you?
I am trying to send a udp message and I look for it in wireshark and I wont seem to find it can any of you tell me is there a problem here? or find me a solution?
Thank you!

```
 DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(5500);
    InetAddress address=InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
     String message="start server";
        byte[] data=message.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data,data.length, address, 5400);
        try {
            socket.send(sendPacket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Your client code works fine for me.  When I point it at a [simple example Datagram server](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html), I can run your code and get a good response back.  Something may be going wrong, but it's not your client code.

Answer (score 0):

How you configured your Wireshark? Is a loopback interface present? If not you won't be able to trace packets send to localhost (127.0.0.1). Try to send them to an other ip for example 192.168.1.100 or else. Don't care if it not exists if you only want to trace the packet with wireshark.

https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback

If your are on a windows system try RawCap packet sniffer http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2011-04&post=RawCap-sniffer-for-Windows-released

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is OK. Packets are being sent (you can try listening for them as well using Java)

Maybe Wireshark is not working for localhost, I think it may not work out of the box. For example, on Windows it does not seem to work, as described in its [documentation](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on Windows or Linux? In Windows you cannot sniff packets with Wireshark, actually with WinPcap, in the loopback interface. https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback

Try sending to other IP address, even if it is not reachable. You should see at least a message going out and then you might receive an ICMP message for unreachable destination.

Code looks OK.

Second, do you have a UDP server listening on port 5400? See if you are receiving something.